# Apache Kafka "max.poll.records" configuration not working

Tags: java, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

I am working on developing a Kafka Consumer, for which I need to poll some limited records from the Kafka channel at a time. I have set the property max.poll.records = 10, but when I start my consumer, I see that it reads all the unread messages from the Kafka at once.
I am not sure why the property is not working, even though I can see the property displayed in the config logs when the Java Kafka Consumer starts.
Below are some of the configs I have:

```
allow.auto.create.topics = true
    auto.commit.interval.ms = 5000
    auto.offset.reset = earliest
    enable.auto.commit = false
    fetch.max.bytes = 52428800
    fetch.max.wait.ms = 500
    fetch.min.bytes = 1
    heartbeat.interval.ms = 3000
    max.partition.fetch.bytes = 1048576
    max.poll.interval.ms = 300000
    max.poll.records = 10
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I see that it reads all the unread messages from the Kafka at once.

So? Since you have `enable.auto.commit = false`, you're in full control over the number of records that actually get processed, then which offset gets committed.

In other words, poll as many records as you want, but only process 10.

---

I cannot reproduce your issue

```
  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    final String topic = "foobar";
    Properties props = new Properties();
    final String bootstrap = "localhost:9092";
    props.put(CommonClientConfigs.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, bootstrap);
    props.put(ProducerConfig.KEY_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, BytesSerializer.class);
    props.put(ProducerConfig.VALUE_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, IntegerSerializer.class);
    log.info("Producing data...");
    try (Producer<Void, Integer> producer = new KafkaProducer<>(props)) {
      IntStream.range(0, 1000).forEachOrdered(i -> producer.send(new ProducerRecord<>(topic, i)));
      log.info("Flushing producer buffer...");
      producer.flush();
      Thread.sleep(Duration.ofSeconds(2).toMillis());
    }

    props = new Properties();
    props.put(CommonClientConfigs.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, bootstrap);
    props.put(ConsumerConfig.GROUP_ID_CONFIG, "consumer-" + java.util.UUID.randomUUID());
    props.put(ConsumerConfig.AUTO_OFFSET_RESET_CONFIG, OffsetResetStrategy.EARLIEST.name().toLowerCase());
    props.put(ConsumerConfig.KEY_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, BytesDeserializer.class);
    props.put(ConsumerConfig.VALUE_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, IntegerDeserializer.class);
    props.put(ConsumerConfig.MAX_POLL_RECORDS_CONFIG, 10); // default=500
    try (Consumer<Void, Integer> consumer = new KafkaConsumer<>(props)) {
      consumer.subscribe(Collections.singletonList(topic));
      final ConsumerRecords<Void, Integer> records = consumer.poll(Duration.ofSeconds(2));
      log.info("Consumed {}", records.count()); // Prints: 'Consumed 10'
      // for (ConsumerRecord<Void, Integer> r : records) { ... }
      // consumer.commitSync();
    }

  }
```

Comment: Then that means, there is no significance of max.poll.records = 10 configuration, if it is going to poll all the records? I even used "max.partition.fetch.bytes" and "fetch.max.bytes" configuration, but all seems to have no effect

Comment: It doesn't poll "all" the records. If you have 1000 records in the topic and set `max.poll.records = 10`, it's not going to fetch all 1000. It might fetch the default 500, but the first returned iterator to the client should only have a size of 10

Comment: Thanks OneCricketeer for the response, but is there a way to set the default "500" to a lower number?

Comment: @Uddhami I don't fully understand your question. Please refer my updated answer

Comment: Thanks for detailing @OneCricketeer. Problem:
`log.("Consumed {}", records.count())`
prints 10 and then in code you have
`consumer.poll(Duration.ofSeconds(2))`
poll in every 2 seconds, but it does not wait for those 2 seconds, bcz it already polled all the (default) unread records and keeps giving in batch of 10.
So, though at a time records.count will be 10, but once we process these records it immediately gives us next batch of records, without waiting for pollDuration.
Once all this events are done, then it waits for the poll duration and makes a call to kafka to consume new events.

Comment: @Uddhami No, it does not pull "every" 2 seconds. It waits **up to** 2 seconds **once** to get 10 records. It will not wait exactly 2 seconds unless there is less than 10 already in the topic.

Answer (score 0):

> max.poll.records:

> This controls the maximum number of records that a single call to poll() will return. This is useful to help control the amount of data your application will receive in your processing loop.

> Default Value
> The default value of max.poll.records is 500

> This setting does not impact the underlying fetching behavior. The consumer will cache the records from each fetch request and returns them incrementally from each poll.

Please refer https://lightrun.com/answers/confluentinc-kafka-connect-jdbc-how-to-use-batchsize

Comment: Thanks for the reply, this means that all the unread records will be polled from Kafka Queue and stored in cache in the consumer application itself?
I thought this configuration, will allow to only poll the given number of records from Kafka.

Comment: "This setting does not impact the underlying fetching behavior. The consumer will cache the records from each fetch request and returns them incrementally from each poll", yes

Comment: yeah it's inside the poll() method, where I am seeing all the unread events at once, not following the max.poll.records configuration

Comment: Why did you link to a page about the JDBC connector ?